# Logging in Identity Server 3

Tags: identityserver3

There seems to be a lot of people asking questions about this, and yet the folks over there have decided to close my question before it's resolved; the perception being that I'm a lazy developer and haven't read documentation - not the case: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/3083

I've followed the instructions here: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/logging.html

but I cannot get logging to happen.
My question really at this point in time is, assuming I haven't done something wrong, does it matter that I'm firing things from a unit test method?

I have a separate unit test project which is just requesting a token and writing the response out, but I'm getting a 500 error somewhere and I'd assume logging would tell me why.

The test was working before I had some repo issues a while ago and lost some work, and I THINK I am back to where I was, but I'm sure the root cause will be something simple that I've overlooked - it usually is.

Anyway, I really hope someone can help, and not just be snotty.
Many thanks!

Comment: I would start by omitting personal feelings and characterization from questions / issues towards people who are giving you time for free, Richard.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @JohnKorsnes but it's not personal feelings, it's factual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed get logging working by wrapping my unit test in

```
 using (var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .MinimumLevel.Debug()
          .WriteTo.File(@"C:\Users\Richard Terris\Desktop\idsLogs.txt")
      .CreateLogger())
        {
```

It's not the best solution possibly, but it works!

Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 1):

First adding logger to IdentityServer Configuration (if Owin, under *Startup* **public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)** method;

```
            Serilog.Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Trace(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp} [{Level}] ({Name}){NewLine} {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
            .CreateLogger();
```

Then adding webconfig the following under ***configuration***;

```
  <system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="Thinktecture.IdentityServer" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="trace.svclog" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
  <listeners>
    <add name="sybsListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="Trace.log" />
    <remove name="Default" />
  </listeners>
</trace>
```

After running, and trying to interact with the IndentityServer, you can check the Trace.log file under your project. Don't forget selecting "*Show All Files*"

[image]

Based on Trace.log, can you specify the problem again if you can't solve?

Comment: Hey @galiperdem thanks for the reply.
I have the config settings as above, and I have tried your code in the startup class, amongst other variations of that.

The current code I have in startup is 
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
              .MinimumLevel.Debug()
              .WriteTo.File(@"C:\Users\Richard Terris\Desktop\idsLogs.txt")
          .CreateLogger();

            LoggingOptions options = new LoggingOptions();
            options.EnableHttpLogging = true;

This doesn't work either and I wonder if it's because I'm firing this from a unit test?

Comment: @richardterris Never tried but if you are using on Unit test project, you probably need to make the configuration under app.config instead of webconfig file since you're not using webserver.